# Ms Word desde c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

Buenas tardes compañeros, tengo un problema para usar MS Word desde C#. Estoy usando Visual Studio 2019 Community y mi SO es Windows 10 (ambos actualizados a la fecha) y sin embargo obtengo el siguiente error al tratar de usar la directiva de MS Word.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A alguien más le ha sucedido esto? Y si es así podrían ayudarme? Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: https://blitchet.com/blog/error-cs0234/ entra aqui

Comment: Gracias Japv, pero estoy programando en Windows Forms y no en Android

Comment: Socio ese es un ejemplo generico lo cual quiere decir que tu error podria resolverse agregando las referencias que faltan, da lo mismo la tecnologia que uses

Comment: Eso supuse y lo chequee, pero no lo relacioné con el área de las referencias. Gracias @Japv y disculpa la novatada, no parecen cosas mías.